# Is the geometric realization of the nerve of a sufficiently nice space homeomorphic to the original space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I tried to convince myself recently that the geometric realization of the nerve of the 1-simplex was homeomorphic to the 1-simplex, but I got a bit stuck. I now realize that I'm not actually sure whether it's even true—can anyone give a proof one way or the other?

To be totally clear, by "nerve" I mean specifically the presheaf on the simplex category given by probing a topological space with the standard simplices—not the nerve of a category or anything.

Comment: No, absolutely not. The geometric realization of $S_\bullet(X)$ is gigantic (because $S_\bullet(X)$ is gigantic). What is true is that the geometric realization of the abstract simplicial set of faces of the simplex (or, generally, of a simplicial complex) is homeomorphic to the simplex, and that for decent spaces $X$ the natural map $|S_\bullet(X)| \to X$ is a homotopy equivalence (not homeomorphism).

Comment: @MikeMiller Can you post a proof that they aren't homeomorphic, then, please? I'm not totally sure how to approach it; I'm probably out of my depth, to be honest.

Comment: Perhaps the "invariance of domain" theorem is relevant... a corollary of it is that the $1$-simplex cannot contain any subset homepmorphic to a simplex of dimension $2$ or higher.

Comment: @LeeMosher Much easier: if $X$ is not finite, then $S_\bullet(X)$ has infinitely many 0-simplices; the 0-simplices form an infinite closed discrete set in the geometric realization and thus $|S_\bullet(X)|$ is not compact. Apply to $X = \Delta^n$.

Comment: This space $|S_\bullet(X)|$ is surely not even a little locally compact but I don't care to think about it. In general if you want to show that $S_\bullet(X)$ can't be homeomorphic to $X$, use how giant $S_\bullet$ is compared to $X$.

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't think it's as direct as that—while you may be able to get an infinite closed discrete set using something along those lines, taking literally "all of the 0-simplices" certainly doesn't work, because, e.g., all of the dyadic rational points get glued to the 1-simplex introduced by the identity map. Perhaps non-dyadic-rational-points don't get glued, but I'm not really sure how to go about proving that.

Comment: That's not what the geometric realization of $S_\bullet(X)$ is... you have either the wrong definition of geometric realization or of $S_\bullet(X)$. Gluings only happen at the boundaries of simplices, not at interiors. Those things have the same image under the natural map $|S_\bullet(X)| \to X$, though.

Comment: @MikeMiller I thought degeneracy maps were also included? Given paths $p, q$ we can form a degenerate mapping $d : \Delta^2 \to X$ which is equal to $pq$ on the bottom edge; then the 1-simplices introduced by $p$ and $q$ are glued to the top edges of the 2-simplex introduced by $d$, and this 2-simplex is in turn glued (by the degeneracy map) to the 1-simplex introduced by $pq$. Then we can iterate this to write the identity as a composition of $2^n$ affine paths, and glue the endpoints of these paths—the dyadic rationals—to the identity's 1-simplex.

Comment: To clarify: This is the degeneracy map I'm referring to, which $d$ is supposed to factor through https://i.imgur.com/JGP295g.png

Comment: Wow, seems like that's the case. This is new to me :) Sorry about the mistake. The essential content of the answer is the same, but you probably want to use $\Delta^n$ of arbitrary dimension. I'll write up an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: Alright, thanks! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65807/discussion-between-benzrf-and-mike-miller).

Comment: To anyone reading this thread: I realized way later that the degeneracy maps do not look like my illustration; the image of a face is always a full face. Honestly, that probably should've been obvious to me from the simplicity of the the combinatorial structure of the simplex category :(